# Implementation of a simple leaderboard for a libGDX game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, firebase-realtime-database, leaderboard

I want to create a simple leaderboard for a game I'm working on. 
It should connect to a database and get the top 5 or so scores, as well as update the leaderboard when someone gets a new top 5 score. Any suggestions on the best way to implement this? I would use Google Play, but that has a registration fee and this is just for a school project. I'm thinking about using Firebase database to store the data, but I hear that libGDX and Firebase don't mix very well.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't they mix well? Both are in Java. You just have to declare an interface in the core Java module for your interactions with Firebase, and implement it in the Android module.

Comment: I was wondering if there were any other libraries (something like google play but for free) that I could use that would be even easier. But if that's not the case, I'll probably just use the method that you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a school project, you could just go with the [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) and store it in there. This is local and easy to cheat but it does accomplish a "simple leaderboard" to give that finishing touch. Another way is to just write it to file and encrypt it for some added security.

Otherwise, if you have a website hosted somewhere, it will likely have a MYSQL server too. You can sent [web/http requests](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) to a php script and store and retrieve it from there in a mysql DB. I did this once and worded like a charm, without the hassle of hosting some random db somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sugestion: Connect to Database, MAKE REST API CALLS using JSON AND USE RecyclerView use data from Database.

Cumps